# Can't switch to code view on google web design

Tags: html, google-web-designer

I just installed Google's new web design software and I seem to not be able to switch out of design mode and into code view. I have yet to see anyone else with this problem.

Comment: Need code and more info on your setup.

Comment: no code, it's mainly an app problem for me. Started a new HTML no pages added a few elements colored them and it wouldn't open from the start

Answer (score 0):

In the top righ there is a Code view button. Click it and it should work for you!

[image]

Comment: Do you have an html file open?

Comment: NO MORE UPVOTES! just had to restart app

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with "Design View" button didn't work. Had to restart the app.